# Cannot share my rss feeds to Linkedin

Tags: rss, linkedin-api, sharing, feed

I use Mac OSX 10.11.6 and I want to share some rss feed news to my Linkedin page. I use a program called Leaf (but used before another one called Reeder). Sadly for some reasons I cannot share the news only to my Linkedin page/Linkedin contacts.... However I can share them to Twitter and other social networks. How come? Why Linkedin prevent me to share the news now (in the past it worked...). Maybe some privacy issues with Linkedin? (I checked my Mac settings and all looks ok to me).

Any help very appreciated-
Andrea

Comment: Hi Andrea, Stack Overflow is more for programming issues. I suggest you try asking Linkedin or the company that makes Leaf directly.

Comment: Hi Eric, sadly Linkedin support pointed me out to this support page:-(